# ExtJS number renderer: hide if zero

Tags: extjs

Is there any way for ExtJs number renderer to display nothing if the number is zero?

Comment: is this for a number in a grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's no complete solution, more some hints; since that int in ExtJS can no longer be null you will always endup with 0. You just can create a custom type that supports null, then you will be able to di this. Or if you don't need any calculations render all into a string.

**Edit:**

By now you can define [useNull](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-useNull) on a field and in addition define a [defalutValue](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-defaultValue). But that's not all you can also define a custom [convert](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert)er and/or a custom [serialize](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-serialize)r. So there shouldn't be any problems anymore when using nullable types.

Comment: By now this has changed. You can now define `useNull` on a field. Along with a `defalutValue` this may enable you to use `null` again. I think you should update your answer with this information.